# Module parse failed: Unexpected token for module.scss file

Tags: css, webpack, sass, webpack-4, webpack-5

I have an error with module.scss as below[image]

Error log: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

My webpack config for scss.module:

```js
{
              test: /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/,
              exclude: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
              use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                    modules: {
                      mode: 'local'
                    },
                    
                  }
                },
                'sass-loader',
              ]
            }
```

And this is a content of my Login.module.scss:

```scss
.Container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .ButtonLoginGoogle {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error? Please give me an instruction. Thank a lot

Comment: Can you share full webpack config file and also your package json to get to know all your versions used?